# influx query: how to get historical average

Tags: influxdb

I am SQL native struggling with flux syntax (philosophy?) once again. Here is what I am trying to do: plot values of a certain measurement as a ratio of their historical average (say over the past month).

Here is as far as I have gotten:

```
from(bucket: "secret_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "pg_stat_statements_fw")
  |> group(columns: ["query"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: sum)
  |> timedMovingAverage(every: 1d, period: 30d)
```

I believe this produces an average over the past 30 days, for each day window. Now what I don't know how to do is divide the original data by these values in order to get the relative change, i.e. something like `value(_time)/tma_value(_time)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few steps you could try:

1. [re-add _time](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/window-aggregate/#recreate-the-time-column) after the aggregate function so that you can have same number of records as the original one:

   |> duplicate(column: "_stop", as: "_time")
2. [calculate the ratio with two data sources](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/calculate-percentages/#calculate-percentages-using-multiple-data-sources) via join and map

The final Flux could be:

```
t1 = from(bucket: "secret_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "pg_stat_statements_fw")
  |> group(columns: ["query"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: sum)
  |> timedMovingAverage(every: 1d, period: 30d)
  |> duplicate(column: "_stop", as: "_time")  
  
t2 = from(bucket: "secret_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "pg_stat_statements_fw")

join(tables: {t1: t1, t2: t2}, on: ["hereIsTheTagName"])
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: r._value_t2 / r._value_t1 * 100.0}))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that - it was a huge bump in exactly the direction I needed to go. I got everything working and put the final code below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Munun, I got the following code working. I made a few changes since my original post to make things work as I needed.

```
import "date"

t1 = from(bucket: "secret_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "pg_stat_statements_fw")
  |> group(columns: ["query"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: sum)
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with window_value: float(v: r._value)}))
  
t2 = from(bucket: "secret_bucket")
  |> range(start: date.sub(from: v.timeRangeStop, d: 45d), stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "pg_stat_statements_fw")
  |> mean(column: "_value")
  |> group()
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with avg_value: r._value}))


join(tables: {t1: t1, t2: t2}, on: ["query"])
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: (r.window_value - r.avg_value)/ r.avg_value * 100.0 }))
    |> keep(columns: ["_value", "_time", "query"])
```